# why sun.misc.Launcher has a public constructor in Java?

Tags: java, classloader

I encountered the following problems when learning the loading mechanism of classes in Java

```java
        Launcher launcher = new Launcher();

        ClassLoader classLoader = launcher.getClassLoader();

        ClassLoader classLoader1 = Launcher.getLauncher().getClassLoader();

        System.out.println(classLoader);

        System.out.println(classLoader1);
```

The results are as follows：

> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5e2de80c
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2

Then I wonder if this is what it means to provide a public constructor For some reason, we want different instances of `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` to load classes. Am I right，and why? And are there any use cases?

Comment: How did you come across this? It is an internal class used by (some versions of) the JDK to load the main class. You should not be using it directly at all.

Comment: If I were to speculate, I suppose it has a public constructor for the same reason we have `new String()` or `new Boolean(false)`. They made them at one point back in the stone age, and now they cannot remove them without breaking stuff.

Comment: `sun.misc.Launcher` is not a inner class.If we shouldn't use it, then why does it have a public constructor?

Comment: `sun.*` is a namespace for internal classes. You are supposed to stick to `java.*`. You won't find any Javadoc for that class, either.

Comment: Java class visibility is limited in flexibility. If you need to call something from outside the same package, you have to make it `public`. Does not mean that it is part of your public API (the one you want users of your library to use). Traditionally, you'd indicate this by namespacing it `sun.*` or `*.internal` or `*.impl`. This has become a bit more powerful now with the modules system, where you can hide entire packages from the classpath.

Comment: what does the class/constructors documentation say?

Comment: @Thilo Thank you for your answer. I got your point. I just google about how to use `sun.* ` package. It is a bad practice to use it，because it causes the code can't run in non-Sun JVM.

Comment: And another reason it is bad practice is that internal classes are liable to change, etc without any notice.  In this case, `sun.misc.Launcher` was deleted in Java 9+.